# Change background colour on table cell and check checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have have a table with the class "pretty".

Each row has a checkbox next to it that selects the data using a form.

I want to be able to click the cell and have the checkbox ticked/unticked.

I have this working using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.pretty tr').toggle(function() {
      $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);  
  }, function() {
      $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
});
```

});

In addition to this I want the cells background colour to change when the checkbox has been selected and unchange if its deselected.

I have not had any luck doing this, any idea's?

I have tried adding

```
$(this).addClass('cssclassname');
```

To the above with no luck :(

Edit just an update the class "pretty" already has the following css which makes the data in the table differ in colour for each row.

It seems when I try the jquery toggleClass function it doesn't apply it over the already existing CSS?

```
    table.pretty {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.pretty th, table.pretty td {
  border: 1px silver solid;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
table.pretty th {
  background: gainsboro;
  text-align: left;
}
table.pretty caption {
  margin-left: inherit;
  margin-right: inherit;
}
table.pretty tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
table.pretty tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/unauu/2/)

An alternative to your Jquery is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tFYca/)

Lets check the demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tFYca/3/)  . I am not sure it is the best way to do it

Comment: Ok tried exactly this, Does it matter that the class pretty already has css properties? If if add them to your demo it no longer works.

Comment: @user, I think adding other classes does not affect toggle class.Please update your question with more details

Comment: Updated the question with more details. Here is an updated version of the website you used http://jsfiddle.net/unauu/9/

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. A lot more jquery then I was expecting for this :P, The only problem now is if javascript is turned off I lose the colouring on the table but that a small issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.pretty tr').toggle(function() {
      $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);

  }, function() {
      $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

`$(this).addClass('class');` will do it...